# Unit testing a DAO class extending a generic DAO class

Tags: java, hibernate, unit-testing, junit4

My generic DAO class looks like:

```
public abstract class DAO<A,B> {
     public Class<B> entity;

     protected final Provider<EntityManager> entityManagerFactory;
     
     @Inject
     public DAO(Provider<EntityManager> entityManagerFactory){
         this.entityManagerFactory = entityManagerFactory;
     }

     public A findById(B id){
        return entityManagerFactory.get().find(entity, id);
     }
}
```

The class I want to write unit tests for looks like:

```
public class TestDAO extends DAO<Test, Long> {
     @Inject
     public TestDAO(Provider<EntityManager> entityManagerFactory){
         super(entityManagerFactory);
         entity = Test.class;
     }
}
```

I am unable to figure out how to initialize stuff for writing unit tests for this class? Any help would be appreciated. The generic DAO would later on also contain functions for updating, deleting, creating etc. I want to use junit4 for my testing purposes

Comment: What is the purpose of the `A` parameter in your `findById` method? You should return instead a `B` type or `List<B>`. In point of view, you don't need a `A` type.

Comment: @HarryCoder A in this context refers to the Test class

Comment: any help with the unit test?

Comment: Why do you return the `A` that reprensent the test class?

Comment: Because I want to find A using B . B is the id (primary key)

Comment: You would have to provide more information about your setup - which build tool, how is your persistence unit initialised, etc.